# set Blocks Bukkit performance friendly

Tags: java, game-physics, minecraft, bukkit

I am currently programming a game, which includes a massive amount of blockplacing.
When a player moves, a stained glass walkway will be set under the player with some block in front and some behind.

I have already checked for duplicate placement and sufficient movement of the player to actually change a distance of one block.

I've tried using the method `sendBlockChange`, but it doesn't help performance because the `sendBlockChange` has to be applied to every online player and anti cheat-Plugins will go crazy.

Below I provided the code for setting blocks during the `moveEvent` and would love to here suggestions to increase performance.

At the moment, a server needs about 5 GB RAM for 3-5 players.

```java
public class MoveListener implements Listener {

    @EventHandler
    public void onMove(PlayerMoveEvent e) {
        Location l = e.getTo();
        // if player is below 254 and is inside the arena and the moved at least 1 block
        if(e.getFrom().getBlockY()<254 
        && YmlMethods.isInArea(e.getPlayer(),e.getPlayer().getLocation())
        && !(e.getFrom().getBlockX() == e.getTo().getBlockX() 
            && e.getFrom().getBlockY() == e.getTo().getBlockY() 
            && e.getFrom().getBlockZ() == e.getTo().getBlockZ()
        )){
            // if -135 < yaw <= -45 or 215 < yaw <= 305
            if ((l.getYaw() <= -45 && l.getYaw() > -135.0) ||
                (l.getYaw() <= 305 && l.getYaw() > 215)) {
                setEWArea(-1, 1, l, e.getPlayer());
            // if 0 < yaw 45 or -360 < yaw <= -315
            } else if ((l.getYaw() <= -305 
                    || (l.getYaw() > -45 && l.getYaw() <= 0)) 
                || ((l.getYaw() <= 45 && l.getYaw() >= 0) 
                    || l.getYaw() > 305)) {
                setNSArea(1, 1, l, e.getPlayer());
            // if -305 < yaw <= -215 or 45 < yaw <= 135
            } else if ((l.getYaw() <= -215 && l.getYaw() > -305) 
                    || (l.getYaw() <= 135 && l.getYaw() > 45)){
                setEWArea(-1, 1, l, e.getPlayer());
            // if -135 < yaw <= -45 or 215 < yaw <= 305
            } else {
                setNSArea(-1, -1, l, e.getPlayer());
            }
        }
        
    }

    private void setNSArea(int x, int z, Location start, Player p) {
        // 3x3 area around position
        int[] positionsX = {-x, 0, x};
        int[] positionsZ = {-z, 0, z};
        // stained glass colors
        int[] blocks = {14, 4, 9};
        
        // player is looking down, let him fall
        if (p.getLocation().getPitch() > 75) {
            for (int i = 0; i < positionsX.length; i++) {
                for (int pZ : positionsZ) {
                    setAir(positionsX[i], pZ, start, blocks[i]);
                }
            }
        // player is looking up, let him fly
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < positionsX.length; i++) {
                for (int pZ : positionsZ) {
                    setBlock(positionsX[i], pZ, start, blocks[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void setEWArea(int x, int z, Location start, Player p) {
        // 3x3 area around position
        int[] positionsX = {-x, 0, x};
        int[] positionsZ = {-z, 0, z};
        // stained glass colors
        int[] blocks = {14, 4, 9};
        if (p.getLocation().getPitch() > 75) {
            for (int i = 0; i < positionsZ.length; i++) {
                for (int pX : positionsX) {
                    setAir(positionsZ[i], pX, start, blocks[i]);
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < positionsZ.length; i++) {
                for (int pX : positionsX) {
                    setBlock(positionsZ[i], pX, start, blocks[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void setBlock( int x, int z, Location start, int data) {
        // get block below player                                     
        Location below = new Location(start.getWorld(), start.getBlockX() + x, start.getBlockY() - 1, start.getBlockZ() + z);
        Material block = below.getBlock().getType();
        // if block is air, set to stained glass
        if (block == Material.AIR) {
            below.getBlock().setType(Material.STAINED_GLASS);
            BlockState bs = below.getBlock().getState();
            bs.setRawData((byte)data);
            bs.update();
            // and schedule removal
            queueBlockRemove(below);
        }
    }

    private void setAir(int x, int z, Location start, int data) {
        // get block below player                                             
        Location below = new Location(start.getWorld(), start.getBlockX() + x, start.getBlockY() - 1, start.getBlockZ() + z);
        // if block is stained glass, set to air
        if (below.getBlock().getType() == Material.STAINED_GLASS) {
            below.getBlock().setType(Material.AIR);
        }

        // get block 3 below player
        Location threeBelow = new Location(start.getWorld(), start.getBlockX() + x, start.getBlockY() - 3, start.getBlockZ() + z);
        Material block = threeBelow.getBlock().getType();
        // if block is air, set to stained glass
        if (block == Material.AIR) {
            threeBelow.getBlock().setType(Material.STAINED_GLASS);
            BlockState bs = threeBelow.getBlock().getState();
            bs.setRawData((byte)data);
            bs.update();
            // and schedule removal
            queueBlockRemove(threeBelow);
        }
    }

    private void queueBlockRemove(Location remove) {        
        Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(Nyanfighters.getInstance(), () -> remove.getBlock().setType(Material.AIR), 20 * 5);
    }
}
```

Notice: There are some code brackets as comments marked. those are all Extensions, which are the target, but already not used to set performance down.

Comment: I don't believe you should be using YML for this, it's very slow to open and close files so many times

Comment: Thanks, I will use yml for it, but will save all the data I need on Enable the method, not on every move. Thanks, that will definitly help

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what exactly you're trying to accomplish? This is a little unclear: "When a player moves, a stained glass way will lead and follow his way and will pass aways after 5 seconds". And you seem to have a lot of unrelated code if that's all you want to do.

Comment: I am setting Blocks under the Player, so if he jumps or walks in air, he is still walking on those blocks because they are set under him. 
The code shows the whole PlayerMoveEvent, with every if-statement and so, that I don't get any help which I already included. 
The setting of Blocks happens in the `setAir()` and `setBlock()` method. The real problem is the scheduler, which removes the blocks. A lot of RAM and CPU is used by this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try implementing a small waiting period between updating the blocks. For example, the first time a player triggers a block update, store an entry in a map, keyed on their UUID and with a value of the current time. Then the next time the event is activated, check that a certain time period has passed between the current time and the last time the event activated. If the specified amount of time hasn't passed, don't do anything. Even if you change it to still update once a second, that will result in a 20x improvement over updating once per tick.

Comment: Thank you, good suggestion, unfortunately the player will walk on those, so one second is to much but with about 250 ms it is still 5 times faster :)